# How to get an array with one dimension in python ?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to have each numpy file from a folder like an array with 1 dimension; This is my code:

```
path ='E:\\t'
traces= os.listdir(path)
print("tempTracesHW_Creation=", tempTracesHW)
for i in range(len(traces)):
   HW = tempHW[i]
   for trace in os.listdir(path):
       file_array= np.load(os.path.join(path, trace))
       print file_array
       tempTracesHW[HW].append(file_array)
```

The result of file_array is:

```
file_array= [[-0.0006447  -0.00094265 -0.0012406  ..., -0.02096185 -0.0210646
  -0.02114679]]
```

But what I want is:

```
file_array= [-0.0006447  -0.00094265 -0.0012406  ..., -0.02096185 -0.0210646
  -0.02114679]
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me please?

Comment: use `file_array[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

The numpy load function loads the file and `return` the `array`.
The `file_array` is two dimensional because your input to numpy.load is two dimensional.
Check the trace file, you need to make it `one-dimensional array`.

For example:

```
example = numpy.save("example",numpy.array([1,2,3])) 

result = numpy.load("example.npy")

print result 

[1,2,3]
```

See if this helps.
More of the code snippet would have help understanding your problem.(About the Trace file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatten` to turn this (1, x) array into a (x, ) array. `flatten` can be used differently, but in this case, it will do what you're looking for.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
>>> a.shape
(1, 5)
>>> a.flatten()
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a.flatten().shape
(5,)
```